# Can a .Net 4.0 assembly be used in a .Net 3.5 application?

Tags: .net-3.5, interop, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference .NET 4.0 assembly within .NET 3.5 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609894/how-to-reference-net-4-0-assembly-within-net-3-5-projects)

Is there any way to ineteroperate a 4.0 assembly (a WPF interface) within a 3.5 application (an MFC Application).  This application is giving us no end of trouble attempting to migrate it to 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are running on different .NET runtimes and CLRs, so unfortunately no, this is not possible.

Comment: But the opposite can be accomplished, no?

Comment: @Jordan - I am not sure, though what I have read suggests that it is possible.