# Mixing 3.5 and 4.0 .net projects

Tags: .net

I have been getting some really weird errors when I have been trying to mix version 4.0 and 3.5 projects. Are they not compatible? Is it possible to make them?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of `mixing` you have and what errors you see? Obviously you cannot reference 4.0 project from 3.5 project. But it should work fine the other way.

Comment: 1) Define "really weird errors." 2) Which way are you integrating them? Are you trying to use 4.0 assemblies in a 3.5 project? That won't work. Are you trying to use 3.5 assemblies in a 4.0 project? That shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I've had no problems using .net 3.5 assemblies in .net 4. The converse is not true, i've had issues MEF failing in a 3.5 application and DirectoryCatalogs when a .net 4 assembly was in the same folder.

there seem to be many related answers:

[How to reference .NET 4.0 assembly within .NET 3.5 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609894/how-to-reference-net-4-0-assembly-within-net-3-5-projects)