# Can I use a .net 4.0 dll assembly reference in a .net 3.5 sharepoint web part?

Tags: sharepoint, reference

I am using some dll's from the crm 2011 sdk in a .NET 3.5 web part.The target is for SharePoint 2010 online. When I try to build it gives me the following error:

`The primary reference "microsoft.xrm.client" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" framework.`

This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework "`.NETFramework,Version=v3.5`". VisualWebPartProjectWebServiceTest.

I cannot upgrade my web part to .NET 4.0 because SharePoint 2010 is not supporting .NET 4.0. Is there some other solution to reference .NET 4.0 dlls in a .NET 3.5 sharepoint webpart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a call to a .NET 4 library from 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761640/making-a-call-to-a-net-4-library-from-3-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say **NO**, you can't use .Net framework 4.0 dll in 3.5 but Yes in the other way around. There are a few workarounds to achieve this, but in a little different way. Check these following SO posts for further reference:

[Can you use a .NET 4.0 dll in a 3.5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791078/can-you-use-a-net-4-0-dll-in-a-3-5-project)

[How Can i use .NET 4.0 code in C# project which is built using .NET framework 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038442/how-can-i-use-net-4-0-code-in-c-sharp-project-which-is-built-using-net-framewo/16040309#16040309)

[Making a call to a .NET 4 library from 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761640/making-a-call-to-a-net-4-library-from-3-5/9508452#9508452)